# Check if a string contains a letter that's input from console

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String that contains a word.
I have another string that holds a letter delivered from an input stream.

When a letter is input, I want to see if this matches with any of the letters that is stored in the String that contains a word.

I have looked at .indexOf() but this returns an integer. I have also looked at contains(), but unfortunately this method checks if the entire string matches to a given string.

Is there a method to see if a letter matches any of the letters in a word?

Thank you.

Comment: *"I have also looked at contains(), but unfortunately this method checks if the entire string matches to a given string."* No, it checks if a given string has another string, not if they're the same (that's `equals`). This definitely is the method you want.  `stringToCheck.contains(letter)`.

Comment: If string1 has "hello" and string2 stores a letter from a user, it won't work, as both are not alike.

Comment: You're not using `contains` then, or you are comparing the other way around (the string in the letter). Check my code on the comment above. `contains` definitely works for what you're asking.

Comment: I feel quite stupid. Thank you for spotting that!

Comment: Happens to all, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it manually -

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
   if(str.charAt(i)==charYouInput){
     //do something eg- return the position of the index 

   }
}
```

Or you may use the `contains()` method with like this -

```
str.contains("c");
```

Assuming you are searching of `char` 'c'. You may use it like a string - "c".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only issue you have with [`indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) is that it returns an integer, and not a boolean, note that as per the Javadoc, if the string is not found, a `-1` is returned.

Thus, your code should work with `indexOf`. All that you need to do is to check if the result of the `indexOf` method call yields a `-1` (meaning that the sub string is not within your original string) or not.

```
String sourceString = "This is a source string";
String toFind = "i";
boolean exists = sourceString.indexOf(toFind) == -1;
```

It would [seem](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) that the `contains` method internally makes use of the `indexOf` method, which would seem to contradict your statement as well. Thus, as per @m0skit0's comment, you *should* use the `contains(String substring)` method.

Comment: Why not simply use `contains`? One less comparison.

Comment: @m0skit0: I misunderstood the OP's question and had to try and find the source of the `contains` method before recommending it, but what you are saying is correct.